# Convert an JavaRDD<ArrayList<T>> to JavaRDD<T>

Tags: java, apache-spark

Is there a direct way of converting `JavaRDD<ArrayList<T>>` to `JavaRDD<T>` using the Apache-Spark's Java API?

```
JavaPairRDD<NullWritable, ArrayList<Record>> baseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(args[2], InputFormat2.class, NullWritable.class,ArrayList.class, conf);  
JavaRDD<ArrayList<Record>> mapLines1 = baseRDD.values();
```

I want to convert the `JavaRDD<ArrayList<Record>>` to `JavaRDD<Record>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<ArrayList<Record>, Record>() {
  @Override
  public Iterable<Record> call(ArrayList<Record> records) {
    return records;
  }
});
```